# lambda функция не работает в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, for, lambda

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
import os
KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: container
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in os.listdir(path='.'):
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=i,on_release=lambda i:print(i))
            )
```

Этот код должен отображать все папки и файлы в папке с py файлом. При нажатии на одну из кнопок в списке, функция `print` должна выводить текст с этой кнопки(i).

Если использовать `lambda i:...`, то она вернёт `None`, если `i` не передавать (`lambda a:`), то будет выводиться только последний элемент.

Comment: print(i) возвращает None

Comment: Еще должно быть: `on_release=lambda i=i:print(i)`

Comment: ```on_release=lambda i=i:print(i)``` Это не работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `on_release` первым параметром передавался объект самого элемента, поэтому `i=i` нужно указывать вторым параметром

Попробуйте:

```
import os

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem


KV = '''
ScrollView:

    MDList:
        id: container
'''


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in os.listdir(path='.'):
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=i, on_release=lambda item, i=i: print(i))
            )


Test().run()
```